# FormAuthentication in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms-authentication

I am quite new in asp.net applications and kinda rusty in vb. Anyway I want to create a web application with forms authentication and I am facing an issue at authenticate method.
**web.config file:**

```
<authentication>
  <forms loginUrl="LoginForm.aspx">
     <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
       <user name="Aaa" password="123"/>
     </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

**login form:**(On Button1_Click event):

```
If (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)) Then
  FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TextBox1.Text, True)
Else
  Label1.Text = "Invalid Crets"
End If
End
```

My problem is that `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate()` always returns False.
Excuse me for writing my code and not sharing it all, but the pc that I am working doesn't have internet connection so I wrote it in another pc.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: This will normally only fail when credentials don't match especially when your config is simple. Also, IIRC, this method has been deprecated.

Comment: Exactly, but as you can see  my username and password are pretty simple and I even copy-paste them in case I was typing something wrong. Also, what do you mean by "IIRC , this method has been deprecated"?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate(v=vs.110).aspx. It clearly states that the API is obsolete. You might want to look at the new Membership API as documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/tw292whz.aspx

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for the clarification, although as I had already found out about Membership from some Remarks in microsoft's page I tried it and raises an error about SQL Server. Anyway I will check it, thank you a lot!